# Storing created macro as Add-In to use on any PowerPoint file without having my macro file open

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-addins

I want to access my macros when I do not have the file I saved my macros in open.

I planned on making an addin, or a functionality in the ribbon, that, when the button is clicked, will run the selected macro.

I created a custom ribbon and stored references to the macros there, but, if the file where the macros saved isn't open, I get an error

> no macro was found.

I then saved my "macro" file as a PPAM, and then, in PowerPoint options --> PowerPoint add-ins, selected the "macro" file PPAM addin.
When I try to run the macros without the macro file open they won't run, and I cannot see the addin on the addin button on the home tab in the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for a step-by-step description of how to do what you're after:

https://www.bettersolutions.com/powerpoint/add-ins/creating.htm

Be sure to save your file after adding the VBA and BEFORE saving as a PPAM.

Comment: Link missing? @steve

Comment: Thanks Steve  -  Though I don't see a link in your answer, I did save the file after adding the VBA and before saving the PPAM.  I also get the alert to enable macros, but when I try to run my macros, it still won't work.  :/

Comment: See my (now edited) reply.  Added the (ahem) Missing Link.